# System.IO.FileLoadException with WebService

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx, assemblies

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I am trying to create a webservice using the assembly [DNSTools](http://www.herdprotect.com/interop.dnstools.dll-bda916146188c8582f711ba0b4f7af82a3572bff.aspx) from Nuance SDK. My WebMethod is really simple : I just create an object from a DNSTools' class, then return "Hello World".

```
using DNSTools;
namespace WebTestFinal
{
    public class WebServiceTestFinal : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            DgnDictCustom dgn = new DgnDictCustom();
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

However when I reach the line :

```
DgnDictCustom dgn = new DgnDictCustom();
```

It throws me this error :

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A0E850E3-91DB-11D1-96DC-0080C72FD13C} failed due to the following error: 8007045a. A dll initialization routine failed. (Exception of HRESULT : 0x8007045A).
 at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
 at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
 at WebTestFinal.WebServiceTestFinal.HelloWorld()
```

I did some research and found out that `System.IO.FileLoadException` was thrown because an assembly cannot be loaded. Despite using `Fuslogvw.exe` and Process Monitor I can't find which assembly is the root of the problem.

Comment: DgnDictCustom is a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) object that is erroring. Contact the vendor of the assembly

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties and in Build Tab, select X86 for platform target, and if it's already X86 change de to 64

In VS - project properties - in the Build tab - platform target =X86